# How to pass variable into the Data.php in Magento?

Tags: javascript, json, magento, php

So I am working on **\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Data.php** at the moment. And I am trying to call a variable but it doesn't seem It's working.

**UPDATE 1**
I have been able to pass the variable by method like this, but I need to declare the product ID manually, is there anything allows the method get the product id base on the product i added into cart?

```
$_productId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
```

is not working in my case.

My test as below:

```
      public function formatPrice($price)
{


    $_productId = 463089; // need to call the current product by the enter the ID manually 
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
    $oldPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice(); //should be the original product price



    return $this->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($oldPrice);


}
```

The result after i refresh my page :
[image]

everything turns to 670

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're "working on \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Data.php", which is the first problem. **Never edit the Magento core**.

Assuming you move this to your own event observer to modify the data, you are loading the product ID with a static variable set to `463089`, then doing nothing to calculate a new price, then displaying the products price.

From your code it makes perfect sense that the price would always remain the same since you are manually setting which product to pull the price from.

It could be a number of reasons why the *quantity* of the item is not changing the price. It might have something to do with other core edits you may have made.

Comment: actually I have successfully pass the variable now but having a new problem with it, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383013/loop-through-the-cart-items-and-return-its-own-id/29383240?noredirect=1#comment46948437_29383240 if u may. Thanks