# loop through the cart items and return it's own ID

Tags: javascript, json, magento, php

I want to loop thought all the items which added into the shopping cart and return it's own ID.

**UPDATE1** :  I have updated method like this

```
   public function formatPrice($price)
    {
        $productId=""; // an iterate here
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

            foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                 $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                 $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
            }


        return 'ID: '.$productId;


    }
```

Now it returns everything in one row therefore i have my result like this, should i use "," to splite them?
[image]

P.S: File i editing is **Data.php** under \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper

I assume the first product's ID is 471186 and the second should be 463089, do i need another foreach loop to do that?

**UPDATE2 :** Even i split it, it will just display like 471186, 463089
but i want it display according to there current product, i assuem i need something else, does the magento library supply some method like that?

**UPDATE3:** I have seen your latest method, which store variable in array and return it. After some modify depends on your code i have:

```
 $productId =array();
 $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    foreach($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
 $productId[]= $item->getProduct()->getId();     
  }

    $productId =array_filter($productId);
        //remove empty array 
        foreach($productId as $id){
        return $id; //return $productId;
        }
```

If i use **return $productId** , it give me "Array" the data type as result which is no use and I tried print out the $id it gives the first product ID only as before.
I will use print_r under this situation but it seem not allowing me to do that.

**UPDATE4:** I tried the internal for loop and i assume it's going to loop and display the price until it's value smaller than $index which is 0 means null.

So i re-factor my codes like this:

```
    $productId =array();
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

foreach($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
     $productId['id']= $item->getProduct()->getId();  
     $productId['price'] = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();   
      }

        $productId =array_filter($productId);
        for($index=0; $index<count($productId); $index++){ 
  return $productId[$index]['price']; //cannot use echo, printf and print_r
            }
```

But it return's null only, nothing display on the shopping cart.
    [image]

Answer (score 3):

In a function you can only return ONE value.
You should concatenate the results for each iteration and then return

```
$productId= "";
foreach($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
 $productId.= $item->getProduct()->getId();
 $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
  }
return 'ID: '.$productId;
```

or use an array

```
$productId =array();
foreach($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
     $productId['id']= $item->getProduct()->getId();  
     $productId['price'] = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();   
      }
$productId =array_filter($productId);
//remove empty array 
for($index=0; $index<count($productId); $index++){ 
 echo $productId[$index]['id'];
 echo $productId[$index]['price'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but i didn't solve it yet, but i'd updated my question please do have a look :)

Comment: @anson920520 `$productId.= $item->getProduct()->getId();`  the dot(concatenation) .. u missed

Comment: split them and use `$myArray = explode(',', $myString);`

Comment: even i split it, it still not the result i'm looking for

Comment: @anson920520 store to array and do a foreach

Comment: i tried the latest code you offer, but it still one step far from the result we want. But thanks you for your help , i have update my question again

Comment: I tried to use your code and modify it myself but it doesn't seem like it works. Thanks